# Creating a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, multidimensional-array, tablemodel

I've been trying to create a table as follows:

```
public class SearchArray {
    public String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
    public Object[] data = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years",};

    JTable table;

    JTable search() {
        table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        return table;
    }
}
```

I, however, keep getting a "no suitable constructor found for JTable(Object[], String[]".

I'm not sure what it is that I'm getting wrong. I'd really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: the best way to solve these type of questions is to ... read the api doc :-) The compiler already narrows it down, so you simply have to read through all the constructors and compare their signature with yours

Answer (score 2):

JTable constructor requires two dimensional array for the data and you are passing one dimensional array as a parameter. Look [JTable Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) for more details.

Two dimensional array should be initiated like this

```
  Object[][] data = {{"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years",""}};
```

Comment: I get an "incompatible types required: Object[], Found String" error when I try using a two dimensional array: public static Object[][] data = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years",};

Comment: It's two dimensional array and you should initiate like this
 Object[][] data = {{"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years",""}};

Answer (score 1):

There is no constructor for `JTable` that takes `Object[], Object[]`, take a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

Instead you could use...

```
public String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
public Object[][] data = {{"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "No"}};

JTable table;

JTable search() {
    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    return table;
}
```

You may also want to take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details and options

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no constructor for [Jtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)  with provided args.

Actual construtor is you are trying to call is  `JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames).`

which allows   `Object[][]`

but your `data` is of type    `Object[]`

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because the values if Object[] data doesn't match up to the reuqired values of String [] columnNames

public class SearchArray {
    public String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
    public Object[] []data = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"}; //two [] [] are required for data of the column 
//Add another data to Object[] data to fulfill the needed amount of data for String[] columnNames

```
JTable table;

JTable search() {
    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    return table;
}
```

}